# Composer (updating) always fails

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

simply i tray to update my composer and this msg is what i got

```
composer could not find the config file: c:\program Files (x86)\composerSetup
to initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting started" section
```

composer.json already exist in the project folder,
and i dont know what is config file in this path (c:\program Files (x86)\composerSetup)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the same folder where your `composer.json` file exists to run `composer update`. Otherwise it will return this error.

For example if you created project `something` and have your `composer.json` file in `public` directory of `something` project directory, you need to go to `something/public` directory and then run `composer update`.

If you don't have composer in your PATH you can go to `something/public` location and then run:

```
php "c:\program Files (x86)\composerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update
```

to update your project

Comment: @smsmwolf did you go to the path where there's `composer.json` file? You need to use `cd directory` in `cmd` to go to selected path.  And when you run `dir` you need to see `composer.json` file and then try to run composer

Comment: yes i did i start from the project folder, i think there is missing file like the msg required in the program files , config file, becouse every command runs without error but the update command

Comment: @smsmwolf You don't need to have any config files in composer directory. I have there only `composer`, `composer.bat` and `composer.phar` and not any config files. You should edit question and dd your directory structure details and exact command you run in your cmd after launching it

Comment: Although my project has the latest composer applied to it's directory my CLI and or MAMP keeps trying to use my global install of Composer which is older. Whenever I attempt to update the global composer however I run into errors such as "can't delete file"... "can't open stream" etc. Does anyone have a clear walkthrough of a bulletporoof way to update Composer globally as I find Composer's own documentation is a real mess.